# Incorrect "Starred" count on chat room overviews

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

I've recently noticed an inconsistency in starred message counts on chat room overviews. I have verified that this bug exists across multiple sites, but will be using [WordPress SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)'s [The Loop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) for illustration.

The starred message count displayed on a [chat room's overview](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6/the-loop) is consistently around twice that displayed in [the room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) itself:

> [image: Starred message count in-room.]
>
> <sup>Starred message count displayed in-room (showing 823 starred messages)</sup>

> [image: Starred message count on room overview]
>
> <sup>Starred message count displayed on the room's overview (showing 1.4k starred messages)</sup>

At the bottom of the latter picture you can see that there are 17 pages of starred messages. With 50 messages listed per-page, it seems to indicate that the count displayed in-room is correct, and that displayed on the overview incorrect (`17 * 50 = 850`).

The exact relationship between the two numbers seems to vary considerably from room to room. For instance, The Loop's overview count is approximately 170% of the actual count, while [SuperUser](http://superuser.stackexchange.com)'s [overview](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118/root-access?tab=stars) count for their [Root Access room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) is approximately 202% of the actual count (though some of this is due to rounding errors made by displaying the count as single-decimal precision thousands).

Am I overlooking something, or is this a bug?

Comment: I think the number in the tab is the number of *actual stars that have been cast*, whereas the other number is the number of *messages which have been starred*. I'm not going to count, though.

Comment: That would absolutely make sense! If this is true, I feel as though the chatroom overview page's design could be improved - to me it would make more sense were the tab to display the number of unique starred messages (just as adjacent tabs display counts of unique instances), and then display properly titled "Total Stars" and "Total Starred Messages" counts within the tab's content.